# Change highlight text color in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Right now, it is a faint gray overlay, which is hard to see. Any way to change the default color?

[image]

Comment: Tools --> Options, in general: Fonts and Colors

Comment: Visual Studio Code, not VS 2013, 2015, etc.

Comment: (For Future Visitors) Also if you need to _disable_ any of these vscode theme colors altogether, you will have to make them _transparent_ using the  two extra `00` hex bits at the end of the color code. E.g., to disable the line highlight background, use: `"editor.lineHighlightBackground": "#ffffff00",`.

Comment: Useful link to copy and paste into User Settings: https://gist.github.com/dcts/5b2af4c8b6918e7d35c4121f11d49fb1

Comment: So many highlight plugins available... here's a nice one: [highlight-icemode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iceliu.highlight-icemode)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Update**
[See @Jakub Zawiślak's answer for VScode 1.12+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43605752/285212)

---

**Old answer**

Visual Studio Code calls this selection highlighting and unfortunately, I don't think the color is customizable currently.  Themes can control the 'selection' color, but the 'selection highlight' color is hardcoded.

See this issue tracking a possible solution: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1636

(As a side note, you can toggle this feature or/off with the `editor.selectionHighlight` setting.)

Comment: ***Obsolete***.

Comment: Updated to reference Jakub Zawiślak's answer for modern versions of VSCode

Answer (score 450):

Add the following lines into "Editor: Token Color Customizations" setting, inside settings.json file.

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editor.selectionBackground": "#135564",
    "editor.selectionHighlightBackground": "#135564"
},
```

See [Theme Color Reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/theme-color-reference#_editor-colors) for more options

Comment: Is there any way to change the text color? Otherwise you have to find a background color that maintains readability when paired with every single color in your color scheme. This is one of two issues that unfortunately keep me from using VS Code...

Comment: Maybe this will help you - [Customize a Color Theme](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_customize-a-color-theme)

Comment: @BrunoBEly If you open `"workbench.colorCustomizations": {}` then start typing `"editor.selection`, the autocomplete menu will suggest all possible keys and their explanation, including the selection foreground.

Comment: @Tobia thanks for the tip! I found it, but am probably doing something wrong. I set both background and foreground to red, but [only background seems to work](https://imgur.com/nCLnFyv) (I'm using VS Code 1.18.0)

Comment: Most of the colors are already used in the editor's text, you can use the transparency property in order to still be able to distinguish the text from the highlighted background

Comment: It stands out better if you set the highlight border color as in @HenryZhu answer below.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/56625325/3585500

Comment: @JakubZawiślak, how about with opacity/transparency?

Comment: Note that `editor.selectionBackground` is for the background behind text that you highlighted (e.g., by clicking and dragging to select with the mouse) whereas `editor.selectionHighlightBackground` is the background color that VSCode applies on text that it matches automatically when you e.g., click on an identifier.

Comment: for the terminal:   `"terminal.selectionBackground": "#f1eeb3a9",`

Comment: This does not seem to work for Python, setting `selectionHighlightBackground` does not seem to affect what color vscode uses when highlighting uses of a variable or function (for example)

Comment: @jrh Try using `editor.wordHighlightBackground` to change the background color that is used for highlighting variables or functions. Works for me for C#, not sure about Python though.

Comment: @Ben Thanks, but unfortunately that did not seem to work. It's still showing Python references (not word matching) in that same neutral gray color that I have a hard time seeing after changing the color.

Comment: Worked for me and really helps to understand code.

Comment: Make sure both colors for `editor.findMatchBackground` and `editor.findMatchHighlightBackground` have transparency (or have some alpha values), in order for `editor.selectionBackground` and `editor.selectionHighlightBackground` to show through the searches. You can keep both colors, `editor.selectionBackground` and `editor.selectionHighlightBackground`, non-transparent (without alpha values) to an extent, and it works flawlessly.

Comment: it worked. But now i want to change opacity

Comment: White space show as `⋯` on selection. If u change the selection color, the color of `⋯` might be too close to it. So u might want to change it too. eg. `"editorWhitespace.foreground": "#71a7ff"`

Answer (score 154):

The above answers cover the **`Selected text`** and **`areas with same content as selection`**, but they miss the **`Current Search Match`** and **`Other Search Matches`** -- ***which have the same problem***.

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editor.findMatchBackground": "#00cc44a8", //Current SEARCH MATCH
    "editor.findMatchHighlightBackground": "#ff7b00a1" //Other SEARCH MATCHES
}
```

Note that the above settings will also affect the colors when using Change All Occurrences <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> *(a super-useful command that* ***intelligently*** *selects all occurrences of a string, placing cursors at each location for multiple-instance editing)*.

***UPDATEs:***

For those using the popular extension [Numbered Bookmarks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alefragnani.numbered-bookmarks) - you can now change the background color of bookmarked lines - makes it über-easy to notice them. *(Have you ever wanted a way to temporarily mark line(s) in your code, as with a highlighter on paper?)* Add this line to your settings.json (also under *workbench.colorCustomizations*):

```
        "numberedBookmarks.lineBackground": "#007700"
```

And don't miss [Henry Zhu's useful tip here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56625325/1447509). I added Henry's tip to the settings above, and find the overall effect improved. *(Henry's tip is not included within this answer - please click the link to read Henry's additional tip)*

[Tom Mai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1016891/tom-mai78101?tab=answers) adds via a comment:

> Make sure both colors for `editor.findMatchBackground` and `editor.findMatchHighlightBackground` have transparency (or have some alpha values), in order for `editor.selectionBackground` and `editor.selectionHighlightBackground` to show through the searches. You can keep both colors, `editor.selectionBackground` and `editor.selectionHighlightBackground`, non-transparent (without alpha values) to an extent, and it works flawlessly

---

**Example of a typical settings file, post mod:**

```
    {
        "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
        "git.autofetch": true,
        "breadcrumbs.enabled": true,
        "git.confirmSync": false,
        "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
        "code-runner.saveFileBeforeRun": true,
        "code-runner.saveAllFilesBeforeRun": true,
        "workbench.activityBar.visible": true,
        "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true,
        "telemetry.enableTelemetry": false,
        "scm.providers.visible": 0, //0 allows manual resize of the Source Control panels
        "editor.renameOnType": true, //Added Aug 2020: renames matching HTML tags
        "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
            "editor.selectionBackground": "#e788ff7c", //Currently SELECTED text
            "editor.selectionHighlightBackground": "#ff00005b", //Same content as selection
            "editor.findMatchBackground": "#00cc44a8", //Current SEARCH MATCH
            "editor.findMatchHighlightBackground": "#ff7b00a1", //Other SEARCH MATCHES
            "numberedBookmarks.lineBackground": "#007700"
            //Henry's tip goes here... (don't forget to add comma to line above)
        }
    }
```

---

**Where to find the settings.json file:**

```
Depending on your platform, the user settings file is located here:

Windows %APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json
macOS $HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json
Linux $HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json
```

**ALTERNATE method to open the settings.json file:**

1. Ctrl + ,  (comma) to open Settings
2. Workbench
3. Settings Editor
4. In the search box at top, paste-in `workbench.colorCustomizations`
5. On the left, click `Workbench` and then `Appearance`
6. Click the link to right: `Edit in settings.json`

References:

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#editor-colors

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_customize-a-color-theme

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

Comment: I found these also useful in conjunction with this answer to find matches at a glance. Note the support for RGBA (in my use, the 75 alpha setting at the end of the color values:
```"editor.wordHighlightBorder": "#00ff0075",
        "editor.findMatchHighlightBorder": "#00ff0075"```

Comment: Thanks for that tip, Neil. I'll try it.

Comment: Anyone knows how this is possible for the matches in the terminal search?

Comment: Thank you for this.  Instead of using `editor.findMatchBackground`, I ended up using `editor.findMatchBorder`, which I set to `#ff0000` (red).

Comment: Hi cssyphus. I appreciate you wanting to encourage upvoting here, but most readers don't even sign in or have an account, so it is really advice for quite a small audience. Since it is meta-advice not relating to the technical content, my advice as an editor is to remove it. I think we can assume that readers who are signed in will know how to upvote (and if we find specific people that do not know this, we can advise them in the comments).

Comment: Feel free to open a chat with me if you'd like to explore more on this theme.

Comment: thank you for the "where to find the settings.json"

Comment: Make sure both colors for `editor.findMatchBackground` and `editor.findMatchHighlightBackground` have transparency (or have some alpha values), in order for `editor.selectionBackground` and `editor.selectionHighlightBackground` to show through the searches. You can keep both colors, `editor.selectionBackground` and `editor.selectionHighlightBackground`, non-transparent (without alpha values) to an extent, and it works flawlessly.

Comment: @tom_mai78101 Thanks for the tip, Tom! (Added to answer, credits to you)

Answer (score 45):

If anyone finds this and, like me, was unable to get the above config working try doing this.

1. go to file > Preferences > settings
2. type in the search *Editor token color customizations*
3. under the *Editor token color customizations* header
4. click on edit in settings.json
5. on the right hand column select user settings
6. paste this into the json object

**Be sure to replace the #'s with colors you want to see.**

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editor.lineHighlightBackground": "#<color1>",
    "editor.selectionBackground": "#<color2>",
    "editor.selectionHighlightBackground": "#<color3>",
    "editor.wordHighlightBackground": "#<color4>",
    "editorCursor.foreground": "#<color5>"
},
```

**My understanding of the above config.**

editor.lineHighlightBackground - when you click on a line this is the color the line background will be.

"editor.selectionBackground" - The background of the word you have selected with your cursor.

"editor.selectionHighlightBackground" - This is the background of selections elsewhere in the file which matches the word you have selected with your cursor. Think of a variable named foo and it's used all over a file. You then select one 'foo' with your cursor, and all the other 'foo' on the page will be of the color specified in this variable.

"editor.wordHighlightBackground" - This is the color of selected text if the default highlight word on click does not take effect. I've only seen this value make a difference if you click on a word that does not auto-select.

editorCursor.foreground - this is the color of your cursor.

Comment: This should be the answer. These are the settings used in VSCode version 1.3+

Comment: editor.lineHighlightBackground doesn't seem to be there anymore, and I think that they're saying it was intentionally removed: https://github.com/dracula/visual-studio-code/issues/68

Comment: that very well could be.

Comment: Thanks, been trying to find this for days, no one ever mentioned wordHighlightBackground!

Comment: This should be marked as the answer. 10 second fix!

Comment: The long descriptions don't really match what I'm seeing, but the list here is what I needed. Helped me style all the important "selection" colors that I wanted.

Comment: actually to be complete this should also add: "editor.findMatchBackground" and             "editor.findMatchHighlightBackground"

Answer (score 37):

As I have tested, setting **border color** makes it easier to read than setting background color, which is what Sublime Text does.

For example, add these lines in `settings.json`:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editor.selectionHighlightBorder": "#FFFA",
},
```

Selected words will be displayed like this:

[image]

Answer (score 30):

you can change it with your favorite color by:

**Steps**

1. Open visual code
2. Goto file menu
3. Preferences -> Settings

after open settings you will update your setting on your right side column, copy and paste this code inside the main brackets `{ ... }`

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editor.selectionBackground": "#f00", // red hexadecimal code
    "editor.selectionHighlightBackground": "#fff" // white hex code
},
```

Comment: Can't put `red` or `white` as values.

Comment: giovannipds, its just name to show, that you can add any color Name, its not value

Comment: That's code, so it's wrong. `red` and `white` are web colors, so that can confuses people..

Comment: VS Code --> File --> Preferences --> Settings, then search for "workbench.colorCustomizations"... copy, paste, done!

Answer (score 8):

This Q&A seems to have evolved into a canonical and the information here is quite scattered and incomplete (there are several different types of highlighting in VS Code!). This is an attempt to defragment/unify/fill.

In general, use subproperties of the `workbench.colorCustomizations` setting in a [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson). You can write colours in the following forms:

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "[Theme Name Goes Here]": { // apply to specific theme. remove this wrapper object to apply to all themes
        // (using the colour red as an example)
        // "selection.background": "#f00",      // #RGB      (red, green, blue)
        // "selection.background": "#ff0000",   // #RRGGBB   (red, green, blue)
        // "selection.background": "#f008",     // #RGBA     (red, green, blue, alpha/opacity)
        // "selection.background": "#ff000080", // #RRGGBBAA (red, green, blue, alpha/opacity)
    },
},
```

See also [the list of supported colour formats](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#color-formats) (already exemplified above).

To make something transparent, set the opacity to zero.

I'll generally only list the "Background" customization point, but know that for many of these, there is a corresponding "Foreground" customization point to change the colour of the text itself, and sometimes even a customization point for borders. Note that you can find most of these yourself by triggering suggestions after typing "`highlight.background`" in a settings.json file inside the `workbench.colorCustomizations` object where a new object key should go.

| Colour Customization Point ID | Description (quoting from tooltip description) | Additional Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `selection.background` | The background color of text selections in the workbench (e.g. for input fields or text areas). *Note that this does not apply to selections within the editor.* |  |
| ⭐ **`editor.lineHighlightBackground`** | Background color for the highlight of line at the cursor position. | See also the `editor.renderLineHighlight` and `editor.renderLineHighlightOnlyWhenFocus` settings. |
| `editor.rangeHighlightBackground` | Background color of highlighted ranges, like by quick open and find features. The color must not be opaque so as not to hide underlying decorations. |  |
| `editor.selectionForeground` | Color of the selected text *for high contrast.* |  |
| ⭐ **`editor.selectionBackground`** | **Color of the editor selection.** |  |
| ⭐ **`editor.selectionHighlightBackground`** | Color for regions with the same content as the selection. The color must not be opaque so as not to hide underlying decorations. | See also the `editor.selectionHighlight` setting |
| ⭐ **`editor.wordHighlightBackground`** | Background color of a symbol during read-access, like reading a variable. The color must not be opaque so as not to hide underlying decorations. | See also the `editor.occurrencesHighlight` setting |
| `editor.wordHighlightStrongBackground` | Background color of a symbol during write-access, like writing to a variable. The color must not be opaque so as not to hide underlying decorations. |  |
| `editor.hoverHighlightBackground` | Highlight below the word for which a hover is shown. The color must not be opaque so as not to hide underlying decorations. |  |
| ⭐ **`editor.findMatchBackground`** | Color of the current search match. |  |
| ⭐ **`editor.findMatchHighlightBackground`** | Color of the other search matches. The color must not be opaque so as not to hide underlying decorations. | Applies for editor find widget and Search View matches, and also to highlighting list items in the Search View |
| `editor.findRangeHighlightBackground` | Color of the range limiting the search. The color must not be opaque so as not to hide underlying decorations. |  |
| `terminal.findMatchBackground` | Color of the current search match in the terminal. The color must not be opaque so as not to hide underlying terminal content. |  |
| `terminal.findMatchHighlightBackground` | Color of the other search matches in the terminal. The color must not be opaque so as not to hide underlying terminal content. |  |
| `terminal.hoverHighlightBackground` | Border color of the other search matches in the terminal. |  |
| `searchEditor.findMatchBackground` | Color of the Search Editor query matches. | [what's a search editor?](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_search-editor) |
| `editor.symbolHighlightBackground` | Background color of highlighted symbol, like for go to definition or go next/previous symbol. The color must not be opaque so as not to hide underlying decorations. |  |
| `editor.wordHighlightTextBackground` | Background color of a textual occurrence for a symbol. The color must not be opaque so as not to hide underlying decorations. |  |
| `notebook.symbolHighlightBackground` | Background color of highlighted cell |  |
| `peekViewEditor.matchHighlightBackground` | Match highlight color in the peek view editor. |  |
| `peekViewResult.matchHighlightBackground` | Match highlight color in the peek view result list. |  |
| `editorBracketMatch.background` | Background color behind matching brackets |  |
| `editorUnicodeHighlight.background` | Background color used to highlight unicode characters. |  |
| `editor.linkedEditingBackground` | Background color when the editor auto renames on type. |  |

If you want to copy paste a skeleton:

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    // "selection.background": "#ff000040",
    "editor.lineHighlightBackground": "#ff000040",
    // "editor.rangeHighlightBackground": "#ff000040",
    // "editor.selectionForeground": "#ff000040",
    "editor.selectionBackground": "#ff000040",
    "editor.selectionHighlightBackground": "#ff000040",
    "editor.wordHighlightBackground": "#ff000040",
    // "editor.wordHighlightStrongBackground": "#ff000040",
    // "editor.hoverHighlightBackground": "#ff000040",
    "editor.findMatchBackground": "#ff000040",
    "editor.findMatchHighlightBackground": "#ff000040",
    // "editor.findRangeHighlightBackground": "#ff000040",
    // "terminal.findMatchBackground": "#ff000040",
    // "terminal.findMatchHighlightBackground": "#ff000040",
    // "terminal.hoverHighlightBackground": "#ff000040",
    // "searchEditor.findMatchBackground": "#ff000040",
    // "editor.symbolHighlightBackground": "#ff000040",
    // "editor.wordHighlightTextBackground": "#ff000040",
    // "notebook.symbolHighlightBackground": "#ff000040",
    // "peekViewEditor.matchHighlightBackground": "#ff000040",
    // "peekViewResult.matchHighlightBackground": "#ff000040",
    // "editorBracketMatch.background": "#ff000040",
    // "editorUnicodeHighlight.background": "#ff000040",
    // "editor.linkedEditingBackground": "ff000040",
},
```

Answer (score 4):

If anyone found themselves reading @FujiRoyale's answer as none of the others worked, and wondered why his/her's also didn't work, but as it was more recent wondered why, I followed their answer, and had (with v1.18 of vscode) this as a `user settings` setup:

```
{
    // Is git enabled
    "git.enabled": true,
    // Path to the git executable
    "git.path": "C:\\Users\\t606964\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Git\\mingw64\\bin\\git.exe",
    "workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
    // other settings
    //
    "editor.fontSize": 12,
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "git.confirmSync": false,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Monokai",
    "editor.fontWeight": "bold",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "files.autoSave": "off",
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "editor.lineHighlightBackground": "#f00",
        "editor.selectionBackground": "#0f0",
        "editor.wordHighlightBackground": "#00f",
        "editorCursor.foreground": "#ff0"
    }
}
```

Note the indentation and commas and removal of double quotes from their answer (which I had to play with to get it right, which wasn't that clear from the answer).  There should be no need to restart vscode, but it may be worth going to `File > Autosave` and see if you start getting primary colour highlights.  And then choose better colours for your highlights.

You can also make this work in `workspace settings` by pasting

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editor.lineHighlightBackground": "#f00",
    "editor.selectionBackground": "#0f0",
    "editor.wordHighlightBackground": "#00f",
    "editorCursor.foreground": "#ff0"
}
```

in between the existing `{}` in that right-hand settings pane.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using/adding extension `Text Marker (Highlighter)` by Ryuichi Inagaki ??

You can select/highlight a selection block, right click `Toggle highlight` to give it a unique color, then continue and repeat with other selection blocks, giving them each different distinct colors which I find most useful!

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Please consider adding a code snippet to show how to use this extension and elaborate how it solves the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can also change the **border** of the selection/search as well, see the below config that contains those and the other values found within this thread already:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "editor.selectionBackground": "#e788ff7c",
        "editor.selectionHighlightBackground": "#ff00005b",
        "editor.selectionHighlightBorder": "#fbf300e0", ##border when you select
        "editor.findMatchBackground": "#f352fe8f",
        "editor.findMatchHighlightBackground": "#8e52fe9e",
        "editor.findMatchHighlightBorder": "#fbf300e0" ##border when you search for something
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Addition:

one can also make settings for a specific theme. See also the [official documentation on themes customization](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_customizing-a-color-theme).

This comes in handy if you sometimes switch between dark and light themes and you want to set different border colors respectively.

For example for a dark theme you want to set a brighter background or border color and for a light theme you want to set a dark color and you could also use wildcards for all dark themes (or at least those that have "dark" in their name):

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "[Visual Studio Dark]": { "editor.selectionHighlightBorder": "#ffffff" },
  "[Visual Studio Light]": { "editor.selectionHighlightBorder": "#000000" },
  "[*dark*]": { "editor.selectionHighlightBorder": "#ffffff" }
}
```

Though I am not very sure if the wildcards are case sensitive and are now also valid for "*Dark*", you may try this out.

Another example, taken from the documentation:

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "[Abyss][Red]": {
        "activityBar.background": "#ff0000"
    },
    "[Monokai*]": {
        "activityBar.background": "#ff0000"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For [Aura](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DaltonMenezes.aura-theme) theme:

I'm using [Aura](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DaltonMenezes.aura-theme) theme and I was having issues with soft highlighting on Aura Dark theme, so I change the colors like this:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
          "editor.selectionBackground": "#6cffd350",          // Current selection background.
          "editor.selectionHighlightBackground": "#6cffd320", // Same content as selection background.
          "editor.selectionHighlightBorder": "#6cffd370",     // Same content as selection border.
          "editor.findMatchBackground": "#ac82ff4f",          // Current search match background.
          "editor.findMatchHighlightBackground": "#ac82ff20", // Other search matches background.
          "editor.findMatchHighlightBorder": "#ac82ff70",     // Other search matches border.
          "bookmarks.lineBackground": "#156ad250"             // Bookmarks extension line background.
},
```

I also added a color to highlight the line when using [Bookmarks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alefragnani.Bookmarks) extension.

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding an answer in hopes this also helps someone. My specific gripe was the lack of contrast between the text you've selected in a partial word, and the rest of the word that auto-higlights. It became VERY difficult to see the difference between what I had selected and what VScode decided to add.

After playing around with the settings, I finally realized that the issue is that it's not using an entirely separate color to distinguish the two, but rather is layering one color on top of the other.

I'd say this decision was a mistake, but is what it is.

The trick: You need to pick colors that are a) transparent and b) when combined, creates a new color.

My example:

> ```
>     "editor.wordHighlightTextBackground": "#ff00006b",
>     "editor.selectionBackground": "#fffb00b4",
>     "editor.background": "#222222"
> ```

The first color is a semi-transparent red.
The second color is a semi-transparent yellow.

Now when I higlight a partial word, I see this:

[image]

Still not as ideal as being able to pick the specific color separately for each of these, but at least there's now a bit more color contrast and I at least know what I've highlighted.

Comment: my answer's quote of docs already says this.