# How to change background color under cursor in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can't find the option in settings to change background color which appears automatically when cursor is on some unity (token?). What's the name of this background color option?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editor.selectionBackground": "#135564",
    "editor.selectionHighlightBackground": "#135564"
},
```

**OR**

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editor.findMatchBackground": "#00cc44a8",
    "editor.findMatchHighlightBackground": "#ff7b00a1"
},
```

for more details see this [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35926381/change-highlight-text-color-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: "editor.selectionHighlightBackground" option does it. TY!