# Change Backgroung Color of Matching Variables In VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSCode highlight matching occurrences under cursor by default
[Highlighted matching occurrences - Default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PynZu.png)

What I want is to change the background color of variables matching occurrences under the cursor. Like this
[Desired highlighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smjyl.png)

The closest I got was with
`workbench.colorCustomization{ "editor.selectionHighlightBackground": "#ff0000" }`
however if the current variable is inside a loop/switch/etc, the outer occurrences isnt highlighte, also I need to have the text selected, not just with the cursor sitting there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change highlight text color in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35926381/change-highlight-text-color-in-visual-studio-code)