# Unable to Find Changing Error Highlight Color

Tags: visual-studio-code, highlight

[Contrast Highlight Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxjSJ.png)

I have read many related question but still unable to fix this issue, can anyone refer any link or help to change the highlight color into something more clear?

Comment: [Change highlight text color in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35926381/change-highlight-text-color-in-visual-studio-code) ?

Comment: this is for the error highlight, not when typing the code

Comment: Visual Studio Code has a page about [Color Themes](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes), with a paragraph on [Customizing a Color Theme](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_customizing-a-color-theme).  You should be able to correct the color there.