# Customize background color of suggested text

Tags: visual-studio-code

Does anyone know whether it's possible to customize the background of a text after it has been suggested by IntelliSense? I'm using the Everblush theme.

As you can see in the GIF, after selecting the suggested `"activityBar.activeBackground"` option in the `settings.json`, I get this annoying white background between the two quotes. This also happens with brackets and with other programming languages (Rust for example).
[image]
Do you have any idea on how to change this?

Keep in mind that this happens only after I press the ENTER key on option given by IntelliSense. It has nothing to do with normal text highlighting.

Comment: have you tried to locate the theme color name in the list of theme colors, if the color changes with the theme it can be customized

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change highlight text color in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35926381/change-highlight-text-color-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following rioV8 suggestion, I found out that the option for this particular case is `editor.snippetTabstopHighlightBackground`.