# How to fix broken settings.json in VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was trying out the customizations from this post (
[Change highlight text color in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35926381/change-highlight-text-color-in-visual-studio-code)) but it broke my VS Code settings.json.

I followed the first answer, the highlighting now works.

But when I click on the top to bring up the "Menu Bar", I get the message:

> Unable to write into user settings. Please open the user settings to correct errors/warnings in it and try again.

```
{
  "workbench.colorTheme": "One Monokai",
  "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
  "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
  "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
  "editor.wordWrap": "on",
  "window.commandCenter": false,
  "workbench.layoutControl.enabled": false,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "editor.mouseWheelZoom": true,
  "html.hover.references": false,
  "css.hover.references": false,
  "less.hover.references": false,
  "scss.hover.references": false,
  "window.menuBarVisibility": "compact",
  "window.zoomLevel": 1,
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
  },
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editor.selectionBackground": "#e788ff7c",
    "editor.selectionHighlightBackground": "#ff00005b",
    "editor.selectionHighlightBorder": "#fbf300e0", ##border when you select
    "editor.findMatchBackground": "#f352fe8f",
    "editor.findMatchHighlightBackground": "#8e52fe9e",
    "editor.findMatchHighlightBorder": "#fbf300e0" ##border when you search for something
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what should I do to fix this issue.

Comment: There is no error in your title. What happens if you remove your customizations to the settings file?

Comment: Unable to write into user settings. Please open the user settings to correct errors/warnings in it and try again.

Comment: After removing it, no more errors. But ofc I need it.

Comment: Remove the comments from the JSON, ## definitely isn't valid.

Comment: Comments should start with `//` , not with `##`

Answer (score 0):

Comments should start with `//`, not with `##`.

VS Code's settings.json follows **JSON with Comments (jsonc) mode**:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/json#_json-with-comments

> In addition to the default JSON mode following the [JSON specification](https://www.json.org/), VS Code also has a **JSON with Comments (jsonc) mode**. This mode is used for the VS Code configuration files such as `settings.json`, `tasks.json`, or `launch.json`. When in the **JSON with Comments mode**, you can use single line (`//`) as well as block comments (`/* */`) as used in JavaScript.

In addition, the editor should have shown you that something was wrong.

[image: screenshot of VS Code with both the valid and the invalid comments]