# How to change the highlight border color for selected words in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm working with Visual Studio Code and have noticed that when I click on a word, all instances of that word are highlighted with a dashed border.

[image]

However, the color of this border is too light for me, and I'm having difficulty seeing it clearly. I would like to change the color to something more apparent.

Could someone guide me on how to adjust the color of the dashed border for selected words in VSCode? Is this something I can set within the user settings, or do I need to modify a theme or install an extension?

Comment: read the theme doc pages for customization, you have to find the theme color name from the list of names

Comment: @rioV8 Yes, I've tried but can't find the corresponding name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson):

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editor.wordHighlightTextBorder": "#ff0000", // pretty sure this is the one for what's shown in the screenshot
    // but there's more:
    // "editor.symbolHighlightBorder": "#ff0000A0",
    // "editor.selectionHighlightBorder": "#ff0000A0",
    // "editor.rangeHighlightBorder": "#ff0000A0",
    // "editor.findMatchHighlightBorder": "#ff0000A0",
    // "editor.findRangeHighlightBorder": "#ff0000A0",
    // "peekViewEditor.matchHighlightBorder": "#ff0000A0",
    // and more... (trigger suggestions to see more)
},
```

Supported colour formats include `#RGB`, `#RRGGBB`, `#RGBA`, `#RRGGBBAA`.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/77662761/11107541 if you want to change the text foreground colour.